# Got column doesn't exist when query nested jsonb field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 11.8 and I have below data in a table:

```
select "uuid", "tax" from "Site" where "uuid"='xxx'

output:

uuid  tax
xxx   {"feePercent": 140}
```

The `tax` column has type `jsonb`.

but I got this error if I select the nested `feePercent` field:

```
select "uuid", "tax"->"feePercent" from "Site" where "uuid"='xxx'

ERROR:  column "feepercent" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes when accessing a key of a JSON element in PostgreSQL, because you actually handing a parameter to a function.

Like this:

```
SELECT "tax"->'feepercent' FROM "Site" where "uuid"='xxx'
```